# Dictionary Getting Released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Currently, I have a class that is parsing XML and sending the dictionary that the XML is parsed to to a view controller.

Here is a snippet of the code that sends the dictionary to the other class (where "response" is the dictionary):

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"SessionData"]) 
{
// We reached the end of the XML document
// dumps dictionary into log
NSLog(@"Dump:%@", [response description]);

// sends dictionary to the VC
CardSetupViewController *setup = [[CardSetupViewController alloc]init];
setup.response = self.response;

//checks
NSLog(@"%@ lololololol", [setup.response description]); //THIS WORKS FINE!!
return;
}
```

At that point, the code works fine. That NSLog marked with //THIS WORKS FINE!! works... obviously. Here is the method in the ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)authorize //this 
{
    AddCard *addCard = [[AddCard alloc]init];
    ServerConnection *connection = [[ServerConnection alloc]init];
    //XMLParser *xmlParser = [[XMLParser alloc]initXMLParser];

    //serverReturn posts the data and is the ACTUAL server response in NSData form
    NSData *serverReturn = [connection postData:[addCard textBoxToXml:
                                                    [self nameOnCardGet]:
                                                    [self ccNumGet]:
                                                    [self expMoGet]:
                                                    [self expYrGet]:
                                                    [self cvvGet]:
                                                    [self zipGet]:
                                                    [self nickNameGet]:
                                                    [self pinGet]]];

    //This takes the information from the server and parses it to "response"
    //Creates and inits NSXMLParser Object
    NSXMLParser *nsXmlparser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:serverReturn];
    //Create and init our delegate
    XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];
    //set delegate
    [nsXmlparser setDelegate:(id <NSXMLParserDelegate>) parser];



    //initiates self.response THIS MAY NOT BE NEEDED
    //response = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    //parsing
    BOOL success = [nsXmlparser parse];
    //error catch testing
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"No errors");
    } 
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing document!");
    }
    //dump   
    NSLog(@"ZOMG CHECK DIS OUT%@", [response description]);
    return NO;
}
```

Basically, the NSLog that states "ZOMG CHECK DIS OUT" is returning (null) and I can't figure out why. No compilation errors, it is a property/synthesize as well. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance. Oh, and please excuse my NSLog comments. I had to differentiate from different parts of the code, and I was in a good mood.

**Edit: I am using Automatic Reference Counting. Don't worry, nothing is leaking.**

Comment: You say that the second code snippet is from your CardSetupViewController, but it looks like it has most of the logic for processing your XML? Please post more complete code from this controller, since in addition to my previous point there is also no indication of how you are initializing your response object.

Comment: I have added the complete method for the second part.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the result the same if you use `[self.response description]`?

Comment: Just checked it. Exact same whether I get the "response" from 'self' or from 'setup', but I find it weird that within 'setup' I can't seem to get the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code block, you generate a `CardSetupViewController` and then leak it. It is unrelated to whatever object is running the second code block. I assume that your second view controller is from your NIB?

Note that you're also leaking your `NSXMLParser`.

Comment: It's not leaked, that's just the snippet of code, not the entire class.

Comment: It's also unlikely to be leaking, seeing as he's said he's using automatic reference counting (although he only mentioned it in a comment).

Comment: This^. Sorry, I'll throw it above.

Comment: @James Martinez: At any rate, `authorize` is never called on `setup`, so if `authorize` is running, it's on a different instance of `CardSetupViewController`. Rob is correct about the source of your trouble if not the specifics of your memory management.

Comment: Authorize is called when a button is pushed.

Comment: @James Martinez: But how is this button connected to the object created on the line `CardSetupViewController *setup = [[CardSetupViewController alloc]init];`? You don't do anything with that object and it's released before you hit the `return;` line at the end of that snippet. If the button is hooked up to anything, it's a different instance of the class. Remember, not all CardSetupViewController instances in your program hold the same instance variables any more than all the NSStrings in your program have the same text.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[response description]`, whatever that is, is probably an autoreleased object that gets released before ZOMG CHECK DIS OUT. Retain it and see if that works. Don't forget to release it when you're done with it.

Comment: Xcode does not let me use Retain throwing an error of "'retain' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode"

Comment: OK, this means you're running on iOS 5 Beta, which is still under NDA. A better place for your questions might be the Apple Dev forums.

Comment: @fzwo: He's not using any NDA features as far as I can tell, so I don't think that's necessarily the case. ARC is publicly released as part of LLVM.